# Is it possible to display data in WSO2 BAM which is analysed by WSO2 CEP?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep, wso2-bam

I have data analysed using CEP which I want to display in BAM.

I am using [KPI analyzer sample](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP201/KPI+Analyzer)

Is it possible to display in BAM? If yes, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you have to write a custom broker that stores the output of CEP to a Database.

The guide to write a custom broker is available at http://suhothayan.blogspot.com/2013/02/writing-custom-broker-for-wso2-cep.html